# What is the proper way in Git for clean up of stale branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull, git-fetch

If I run `git fetch --all --prune` does this remove stale branches locally or does it first fetch all branches from clones and then does the cleanup.
I noticed a case where I did `git push --delete origin some_branch` from a machine and then when in another complete instance after doing `git fetch --all --prune`and *then* `git pull` the branch still was there.
I don't understand this behavior, what is the proper way to clean up stale branches?

Comment: I learned something new from Atlassian's response to this question:
`git prune is generally not executed directly. Prune is considered a garbage collection command and is a child command of the git gc command.`
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-prune

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be aware that `--all` in `git fetch` means *all remotes*, not *all references*.  That is, if you have the usual single remote named `origin`, `--all` does nothing at all.

Next, keep in mind the difference between a *branch name*—a name in `refs/heads/`, such as `refs/heads/master`—and a *remote-tracking name*, sometimes called a *remote-tracking branch name*, which is a reference under `refs/remotes/` followed by the name of the remote.  What `--prune` does is to remove remote-tracking names that have no corresponding name on the particular remote.

What `git fetch` normally does is:

1. Call up the Git at the URL stored with that remote, e.g., the one from `git config --get remote.origin.url` when fetching from `origin`.
2. Have them list their reference names (run `git ls-remote` to see these).
3. Converse with that Git to obtain Git objects—mostly commit objects, but any objects from the output in step 2 are candidates—that they have, that we don't, that we want (based on any additional arguments given to `git fetch`, or the configured setting).
4. Finally, after obtaining all objects, create or update local names, typically of the form `refs/remotes/remote/name`, based on the branch names seen on that remote.  But see below, because this step has complications.

   It's during this update that your Git may *remove* some of these remote-tracking names, if you've enabled pruning (via `--prune` or configuration options).  This is all well before `git pull`, which runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, can run its second Git command.

Last, note that for `--prune` to work correctly, you need a typical `remote.remote.fetch` setting, e.g., `remote.origin.fetch` would read `+refs/heads*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, and then `git fetch --prune` would remove, from your own repository, a `refs/remotes/origin/xyzzy` if there is no `refs/heads/xyzzy` in the Git repository at `remote.origin.url`.  If you have made a `--single-branch` clone, the `remote.origin.fetch` line will have different content and `--prune` will be ineffective.

Given what you observed, it seems likely that you had a nonstandard `remote.origin.fetch` setting, probably due to having created the clone as a single-branch clone.

Comment: What is a single-branch clone and how do I check the settting `remote.origin.fetch` to verify?

Comment: I didn't understand how to solve it, i.e. how to force the cleanup

Comment: Use `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` to see what `remote.origin.fetch` is set to. A single-branch clone is one you get by running `git clone -b <branchname>` or `git clone --single-branch`.

Comment: That displays: `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. So does that mean single branch clone?

Comment: What is the best way for a clean up in the machine?

Comment: I see that if I run: `git fetch --all --prune` and then `git branch -a` one exactly after the other the branch is listed as local since it does not have the prefix `remotes/origin/`. How can I clean it up?

Comment: That's a normal (non-single-branch) clone. And if `git branch -a` does not list it under `remotes/origin/`, then yes, it's a (local) branch; fetch will not prune it. If you run `git branch -d <name>`, your Git will delete it if that operation is safe (meaning, you won't lose any commits). If you're sure you want to delete it even if it's *not* safe (might lose commits), you can use `git branch -D <name>` (uppercase D-elete to force deletion). Newer Git versions also accept `git branch --force -d <name>`.

Comment: But why does it do that? I mean if the remote branch is deleted why does fetch leave it local? Is the expectation that it needs to be a local clean up for safety? I thought that if the remote branch has been deleted then doing a prune locally should the state i.e. branch refs consistent with remote. Apparently it does not

Comment: Because your branches are *yours*. Why should what I do on my Git repository, or anyone else does on anyone else's repository, change *your* branches?